# Odoo - Remove internal reference from Sales Order report

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11, odoo-view

I am using Odoo 10 and I dont want the Product Internal Reference(default_code) printing on the Sales order report. I only want to remove from the report so customer cannot see the Internal Reference.

I tried below I seen on another post but it didnt work.

```
<!-- remove internal reference form Sales report.-->
<template id="sale_order_fields_inherit_saleorder_document" inherit_id="sale.report_saleorder_document">
    <strong><span t-field="l.product_id.name"/></strong>
</template>
```

Comment: are you saying about Customer Reference/Your reference in SO Report.

Comment: The products internal reference [default_code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inherit the `sale_order_document report` and replace the `l.name` with `product_id.name` here is complete code:

```
<template id="sale_order_fields_inherit_saleorder_document" 
    inherit_id="sale.report_saleorder_document">
    <xpath expr="//span[@t-field='l.name']" position="replace">
        <span t-field="l.product_id.name"/>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

you can try this one !!, may be it'll help you.!